# Experiencing this error while building flutter app on MacOS: /Users/ggg/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error:

Tags: ios, xml, flutter

Am trying to build my flutter app to work on ios. Am coming from Windows OS and everything was fine there but this is the first of multiple issues am encountering when I try running the app on MacOs.

/Users/ggg/Desktop/app/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Encountered unexpected element at line 50 (plist can only include one object) / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0.

Here is my info.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to camera when user prompts it.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to photo library when user prompts it.</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>appname</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-44919293838389292~763277283</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>cstr6.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```